# Reading a process memory with Python3 on OSX

Tags: python, macos

I've been searching how to read a process memory adresses in Python3 on OSX without finding a good and simple way to implement this (I'm new to Python3 and OSX). 
I'm aiming at real time analysis (no pause on the process to analyse), and an efficient way to get those variables without having to dump the whole memory.

It seems like ptrace is not the right tool for this issue, and Mach library of OSX (giving access to vm_read functions) doesn't seems to be available on Python3.

I get that I need to spawn a child process with something like the subprocess import in order to get the rights to actually read the memory.

Does anyone have any clue on this issue ?

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879631/reading-writing-another-process-memory-in-python-running-on-os-x.

Comment: The wrapper seems outdated and out of reach with my current understanding of Python; the ctypes solution seems much easier to get but is rather vague - can't find any relevant information with a search on StackOverFlow and Google (where to search for the library? etc)

Comment: If building an extension module in Python is out of reach for you (and if OS X and Python are new), I don't know that this is the best solution. Are you sure you need the information in Python? Can you use the built-in Instruments application on OS X? This allows you to view lots of information about another process, including its memory allocations.